# How to setup touchegg with gnome 3.18 on ArchLinux?

Tags: arch-linux, touchpad, gnome3

I'm running ArchLinux (Antergos) with Gnome `3.18.4` installed. I can't make touchégg work for multitouch gestures.
I installed `touchegg-git` from the Aur (also tried `touchegg`). When I launch it, I only get

```
$ touchegg
Reading config from  "/home/dev/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf" 
Try to make a multitouch gesture. If everything goes well the information about the gesture must appear 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Flick 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Drag 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Pinch 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Rotate 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Tap 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Touch
```

But no gestures get recognized.

However, when I start touchégg from an Openbox session, the three and four fingers gestures work !

So do you know why gnome prevents touchégg from working and how to make it work correctly, at least for 3 and four fingers gestures ?

I've disabled `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse` using dconf-editor.

I use a macbook air, so it's an apple trackpad. Here is the output of my `xinput` :

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer      (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ bcm5974                                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad id=10[slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Built-in iSight                           id=12   [slave keyboard (3)]
```

and `xinput -list-props 11` :

```
Device 'bcm5974':
Device Enabled (142):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (275): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (276):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (277):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (278):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (279):  136, 2784, 110, 1442
Synaptics Finger (280): 70, 75, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (281):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (282):   522
Synaptics Tap Durations (283):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (284):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (285):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (286):    283
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (287):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (288): -237, -237
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (289): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (290):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (291): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.016855, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (292):    0
Synaptics Locked Drags (293):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (294):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (295): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Click Action (296):   1, 0, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (297): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (298):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (299): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (300):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (301): 1
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (302):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (303): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (304):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (305): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Grab Event Device (306):  0
Synaptics Gestures (307):   0
Synaptics Capabilities (308):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (309): 1, 1
Synaptics Area (310):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (311):  3540, 0, 5500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (312): 39, 27
Device Product ID (265):    1452, 576
Device Node (266):  "/dev/input/event6"
```

And here is my `synclient` :

```
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 136
RightEdge               = 2784
TopEdge                 = 110
BottomEdge              = 1442
FingerLow               = 70
FingerHigh              = 75
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 522
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 283
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = -237
HorizScrollDelta        = -237
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0168549
TouchpadOff             = 0
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 0
TapButton2              = 0
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 0
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 1
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 0
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 39
VertHysteresis          = 27
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3540
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 5500
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work ! 
I looked around a lot on the net, and a lot of people have got troubles with touchégg. 
I'm going to make a tutorial on how to make it work and I'll link it to this post.

Anyway, the important part is to start touchégg BEFORE starting gnome. This can be achived by editing your .xsession and your session manager settings.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with that tutorial?

Comment: I use libinput-gestures now, it works much better than touchégg.